# Why is $1-\Phi (-0.5)= \Phi (0.5)$?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Given the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution
$$\Phi(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \, ,$$
why is $1-\Phi (-0.5) = \Phi (0.5)$?

Comment: At a bare minimum you need to say what $\Phi$ is.  Adding context (explaining why you want this answered) and showing what attempts you've already made and where you got stuck are the best ways to avoid downvoting and closure

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: your shaded areas  seem to be $\Phi(0)$ and $1-\Phi(0)$

Answer (score 3):

The pdf $\phi(x):=\Phi^\prime(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ is even, so $\Phi(-a)=\int_{-\infty}^{-a}\phi(x)dx$ is equal by symmetry to $$\int_a^\infty\phi(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^a\phi(x)dx=1-\Phi(a).$$